Getting blank value when calculating query param in aws api gateway Integration responses
I am facing problem with mapping data into response in aws gateway mock API mapping templte of integration response. Below is my scenario
I am passing age integer value as query parameter of mock endpoint.
When I accessing age parameter using below way it is working perfectly
#set($ageValue=$input.params('age'))
above mapping template, giving below response as expected when I passed query param age value as 10
{
        "ageValue": 10,
}

But when I add some calculation logic to age it is getting not working and giving blank response
#set($ageValue=$input.params('age')*10)

When I change mapping template as above, it is not working and gives empty value as response
{
        "ageValue":,
}

I have tried below ways and not worked

$Integer.parseInt($input.params('age'))*10
$input.params('age').toInteger()*10

Is there any way to fix this issue??
